# multipatch features are not visible in 3D ArcGlobe

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, arcglobe

I have created some 3D features in ROCKWORKS software, which represents lithology data. Then I converted it to 3D shapefile, and then I added it to ArcGlobe as well as ArcScene. It is clearly visible in 3D in ArcScene but in ArcGLobe it is not visible as 3D.  Instead it is just visible as a 2D Feature class.  Then later I have tried some extrusion options, but that graphic rendering is not good like ArcScene, and I have tried some other options like some sketch up files I have converted to multipatches but the same problem .  Is there any way to add 3D symbology from ArcScene to ArcGlobe?  Actually, I want to show lithology data like in the following link, and I want to create one globe service, how to do it.....

http://blogs.esri.com/Info/blogs/arcgisexplorerblog/archive/2011/04/15/3d-subsurface-profiles.aspx

Thanks and regards
Srinivas

Comment: Somehow your link did not make it into the question...